# Set default language for new window/app in Mac OS

Tags: macos

In Windows I can set a default language for each window/application. So whenever I open any new application input language is automatically changes to default. This allows me to chat with my friends via Skype in one language and write code in IDE in another language without having to switch input every time I go to Skype/return to IDE.

Is there a way to set up something similar in Mac OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 10.6 ~ 10.8, you can go to the `Language & Text` system preference, then the `Input Sources` tab.  There is an Input source option to **Allow a different one for each document**, which should do what you want.  It may depend on if the app allows it.  For me, switching between terminal and safari for example, the setting worked.

The setting has changed slightly in 10.9; but, that is pre-release software and can't be discussed here.

Answer (score 3):

In 10.9 go to System preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard preferences... (button in the bottom right corner) -> Input Sources (tab)
and select "Automatically switch to a document's input source."

Answer (score 0):

If others search for how to change the language of an application UI, you can add an AppleLanguages array to the plist of an application:

```
defaults write -app Calculator AppleLanguages -array de
```

It doesn't change the input sources used when the application is focused though. See `defaults read -g AppleLanguages` for the language identifiers.